# How to change the extent of raster layer to lat lon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, latitude-longitude

For species distribution modelling I am working in R with rasters obtained from QGIS. To be able to work with my data, both my rasters and point variables need to be saved in similar extent format. Since my point data is in lat long format, I have tried to transform the saved extent of my clipped raster to lat long as well but I have thus far not been successful.

To illustrate, I have clipped my datafile to a mask of the study area, which is noted down in my desired lat long format.

[image]

However, when I go to the properties of the clipped datafile, the extent is again noted down in the QGIS format rather than my desired lat long format.

[image]

I have tried a lot of different methods to try and figure ths out but have thus far not been successful.

Comment: Have you tried `reprojecting` your raster data to WGS 84 ?

Comment: Nope, my data is already in EPSG:32619 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 19N. What would reprojecting do exactly regarding the extent coordinates?

Comment: WGS 84 aka EPSG 4326 is the "lat lon format" you seem to need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried this solution multiple times, however, my raster extent weirdly does not seem to line up with the lat lon format (edit: when changing the CRS to align with my output, so EPSG 4326). 
What I am aiming for is around -69.48800, -12.85400, but changing the crs of the raster makes it xmin 391185, xmax 619815, ymin -1555215, ymax -1322685